# How to examine and debug Yocto's bootloader on i.MX6Q?

Tags: linux, bootloader, yocto, imx6

I am building a trusted execution environment on IMX6Q with a Linux Yocto version in the untrusted processor mode. When I switch to non-secure for the first time after reset to load the linux kernel, I get flooded with data and prefetch abort exceptions after I jump to the kernels bootloader.It also seems like, that those exceptions occur as soon as the MMU is switched on.

Booting the Kernel without changing to non-secure state works fine.

Is it possible, that the control bits of the non-secure copy of the first-stage page tables are written with the NS-Bit cleared which causes the MMU to refuse any access to those regions ?

Where can I find the startup code that is setting up the page tables in the Yocto-BSP for IMX6Q ?

How can I debug the Linux Bootloader?

Is it possible to simply change source code of the bootloader in the build-directory of the BSP and rebuild the image?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I debug the Linux Bootloader?

Yes, you can with beautiful `printf`/`puts`... BTW if you want to really debug with `jtag` in early stages of `uboot` you can refer to [this NXP forum post](https://community.nxp.com/thread/324900)

> Is it possible to simply change source code of the bootloader in the build-directory of the BSP and rebuild the image?

You can easily work with the git directory of u-boot in your `workbuild/tmp/work/.`. dir

1. Modify what you need
2. compile it with `bitbake -f -c compile u-boot-imx`
3. Deploy it with `bitbake -f -c deploy u-boot-imx`

At the end your new u-boot will be placed in usual `workbuild/tmp/deploy/images/...`